# An algorithm to calculate the square numbers for the middle four squares on a game board?

Tags: python

I am creating a program that creates a console version of othello or reversi on python 3.3. I am in the process of creating the board which requires the user to input an EVEN row number between 4-16 and an EVEN column number between 4-16. How can I make a function or algorithm that determines the four square numbers on the user defined grid that places the initial four pieces in the middle  the board? Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Supposing the numbers of rows and columns are the values of `rows` and `cols`, the row numbers to use are `rows/2-1` and  `rows/2`.  (Eg, if `rows==12` the values are 5 and 6.)  Similarly, the column  numbers to use are `cols/2-1` and  `cols/2`.

Note, if the board is represented as a linear array, and if cells of a row are stored adjacently, you can say `lr =(rows+1)*cols//2`, and initialize cells 'lr', `lr-1`, `lr-cols`, and `lr-cols-1` as the center cells.  This is equivalent to the formulas above.  For example:

```
for rows in (4,6,8):
    for cols in (4,6,8):
        lr = (rows+1)*cols//2
        r = rows//2
        c = cols//2
        print rows, cols, ':\t', r,c, '\t', lr-cols-1, '\t', lr-cols, '\t', lr-1, '\t', lr, '\t', r*cols+c
```

produces

```
4 4 :   2 2     5   6   9   10  10
4 6 :   2 3     8   9   14  15  15
4 8 :   2 4     11  12  19  20  20
6 4 :   3 2     9   10  13  14  14
6 6 :   3 3     14  15  20  21  21
6 8 :   3 4     19  20  27  28  28
8 4 :   4 2     13  14  17  18  18
8 6 :   4 3     20  21  26  27  27
8 8 :   4 4     27  28  35  36  36
```

That is, the subscripts for the (4,6) case are  (8,     9,  14,     15)   and for the (6,4) case are  (9,   10,     13,     14).

For even integers, 2 is an exact divisor, so I think the result with / will be the same in both Python 2 (where integer division truncates) and  Python 3 (where it doesn't).  Or you can use the `//` operator to be sure of  truncating division.

Note, you can test that `rows` and `cols` are even by an expression like `(rows|cols)&1`, which is 1 if either is odd, else is 0.

Comment: can you clarify a little bit further? say that the user wants a 4x6 board, which would make the 4 middle pieces 10, 11, 14, and 15, and in a new game wanted a 6x4 which would make the middle pieces 9, 10, 15, 16. When I try to use your method, it doesn't work out.

Comment: @LeonardYi, see added table.  I think your numbers 10, 11, 14, and 15 and 9, 10, 15, 16 are incorrect.  They should  instead be  (8, 9, 14, 15) and (9, 10, 13, 14) [when storing by rows] or vice versa [when storing by columns].  Row, column, and cell numbers being zero based.